# ANN model not improving accuracy

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train an ANN with 2 Hidden layers of size 32 neurons each and ReLU activation function. The input has a size of 14 and output layer has one neuron with activation function Sigmoid.
When I try to train it, it improves the accuracy and loss only in the second epoch.

I was expecting for the accuracy to improve over the epochs but this did not happen and the accuracy remained the same. I am attaching the dataframe description and code here.
[image: Dataframe description]

I am trying to predict the Exited label.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

X = df.drop("Exited", axis = 1)
y = df["Exited"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
X_test, X_val, y_test, y_val = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(14,)),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

m1 = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=128, epochs=100,
          validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

The output when I fit the model is:-
[image: Output produced in First 10 epochs]

The case remains the same for the remaining 90 epochs as well. The training loss remains constant at 0.5108 and validation loss at 0.5003 after some epochs.

Where am I going wrong? Is it my model or something else?

Answer (score -1):

Use standardization or normalization technique before feeding it to the network.
You can use it in this way:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScalar
sc = StandardScalar()
X_train = sc.fit(X_train)
X_train = sc.transform(X_train)
X_val = sc.transform(X_val)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```